# how to align subviews to the center of parent view?

Tags: ios, ios6

I create a CenterContainerView, which contains imageViews, after I add an imageView to CenterContainerView, the subviews of CenterContainerView are automatically aligned to center, I don't know how to implement it, I think may be I should use autoresizing mask to do it, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To align subviews to the center of superView use the center property of a view.

`imageView.center = CenterContainerView.center`;

Comment: but if I have 4 imageViews, what can I do?

Comment: Do you want to add all the imageViews to the same containerView, and display all of them simultaneously?